# Modeling accounts of different type

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am having a really hard time finding out the domain model for handling different types of owners in a real estate domain (more precisely rental management).

Let’s imagine Bounded Contexts:

- IAM (users / accounts, access…)
- Owners (imagine a registry of owners
- Rental Management (tenants, properties, …)

There are a few types of users:

- internal to the platform (admin, agents, …)
- tenants
- owners

There are 2 types of owners:

- Persons (individuals)
- Companies

Whenever an owner is registered, a new account is also created to grant them access to the platform.

Therefore, the registration of an owner generates an Account in BC IAM, and an Owner in BC Owners.
I figured that domain events would help in handling that sequence very easily.

But my first issue would be the identification information: a person has a first and last name etc, but a company would only have a name.

Should the Account object know of this « naming » of an owner ? I feel like it is too specific, but at the same time, I feel like if Account only contained « email » and « password », it would be very thin.

Same applies with Tenants.

An idea that I am exploring is that user types are defined in their respective Bounded Contexts, pointing to their account in the IAM BC: does it look like a bad design ?

It would be very difficult in such a design to actually identify a User behind an Account, and there is a need to list all users in the platform in one place, for administration purposes.